# Xamarin f# interactive console won't evaluate expression

Tags: f#, xamarin, xamarin-studio, f#-interactive

I am trying the F# example project with Xamarin Studio.

If I send a selection to F# interactive everything works, however I can't work out how to just type something into the REPL and evaluate it?  Is this not possible? Can I only write stuff in the editor and send it to the REPL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the F# interactive REPL you need to end your commands with double semicolon.

```
> 1 + 2;;

val it : int = 2
```